# maps offline with phonegap or cordova

Tags: android, cordova, maps

Is there a way to integrate a map offline with phonegap or cordova. I found this interesting link maps.me but I am not sure if it works ok with phonegap.

My goal is only for android

Greetings

Comment: Not sure, but you might be able to use the cordova googlemaps plugin and manually configure the native google maps to store the maps in cache. I have some experience with the js api and there you can change the tile source, so you could download all tiles on the device and use them offline. Both don't look like production solutions though.